# The data has been deleted in source of recruitment module. But it still appears in the selection box. Is that an error or bug in Odoo 13?

Tags: odoo-13

Currently, I can create for source's data (Test) and after that delete it from Configuration --> Source of Applications too. But it still appears in the selections box like this.

Already deleted it (Test).

[image]

But it (Test) still appears in the selections box.

[image]

So that is the bug or error of Odoo 13 or How to delete it?

Comment: Is it in database ?

Comment: No, it's not in the database.

Comment: Try via re-installing module which contains this table